# Why word-break nor word-wrap nor overflow-wrap are working in my CSS? What am I doing wrong?

Tags: css, word-wrap

I have a button with the username in it. I'm using Bootstrap 4.

Just in case it's too long, I want to break the name if it is longer than a certain size. I don't want the button to get bigger than a specific size.

Here's my button:

```
<div class="romperNombre">
<li class="navbar-item dropdown">
<button class="btn btn-sm btn-light" type="button">
<strong>MariaJuanaJuliaMartinezCorreaFernandez</strong>
</button>
</li>
</div>
```

I don't get the name to break. Even if I use

```
<strong>Maria Juana Julia Martinez Correa Fernandez</strong>
```

instead of

```
<strong>MariaJuanaJuliaMartinezCorreaFernandez</strong>
```

Here's my class:

```
.romperNombre {
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  word-break: break-all;
  hyphens:auto;
  max-width:100px;
}
```

And I've tried adding the class to the button itself, and doing in CSS:

```
.romperNombre button {
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  word-break: break-all;
  hyphens:auto;
  max-width:100px;
}
```

I've also tried `button .romperNombre {}`

Why it's not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `white-space: normal` to your button:

```css
.romperNombre button {
  white-space: normal;
  
  word-break: break-all;
  hyphens: auto;
  max-width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="romperNombre">
  <li class="navbar-item dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-sm btn-light" type="button">
<strong>MariaJuanaJuliaMartinezCorreaFernandez</strong>
</button>
  </li>
</div>
```